# Trouble understanding radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm going through my analysis book's discussion of the radius of convergence and having trouble following. So from my current understanding, let $(c_n)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers, a disk with radius r is defined as
$B_{r}(0)= \{z\in\mathbb{C}|\space|z|<r\} $, then a sequence of functions $s_k:B_r(0) \to \mathbb{C},  s_k(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} c_nz^n$

It can be shown that this sequence of functions converges absolutely uniformly if for some

$z_0\in\mathbb{C},|z_{0}|>r \space \exists M\in\mathbb{C}: |c_nz_{0}^n|<M \space \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

by using the property that a series of functions $(s_k:D\to \mathbb{C},s_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} f_n(x))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges absolutely if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ||f_n(x)||_{D}$ converges. I am unsure of this however since in the book the theorem was only proved for real valued functions

The fact that the sequence of functions converges absolutely uniformly has been shown, what does this have to do with the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{k} c_nz^n$ evaluated at a specific z? Is the previous definition of convergence of a series overhauled, and convergence of these series redefined through the property that for a fixed sequence of complex numbers, the function sequences of functions of the form $f_{k}(z):B_{r_1}(0)\to\mathbb{C}, f_{k}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} c_nz^n$ $g_{k}(z):B_{r_2}(0)\to\mathbb{C}, g_{k}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} c_nz^n$ absolutely converge to output the same value for a value of z that is in both disks?

I have inserted the relative pages of my book, I do not know how much help that will be however seeing that they are in German

[image]

[image]

[image]